# Parse a string to array where keys are separted by colon

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am trying to parse string to an array for searching purpose. like I have this string:

```
$string = 'is:issue is:open user:john Hello world';
```

I want this to array like:

```
array(
    'is'        => array('issue', 'open'),
    'user'      => 'john',
    'q'         => 'Hello world'
);
```

I tried to use explode, but can't figure out how to catch colon separated words and last query string.

Thanks

Comment: whats the source of the string?

Comment: Source mean this $_GET['s'] ?

Comment: are you posting this or is something else posting it to you?

Comment: This string was submitted by user from search form, so I can get the variable using `$_GET['s']`.

Comment: edit the form so you get it in a useable format

Comment: I know that as well but that's not my question

Comment: well its my answer - if your only interested in doing it the hard way, I'll leave ya to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input format is not ideal but it shouldn't be too hard. We split by spaces, process each part as a pair and when we reach a part that can not be processed as such, assume it's the query.

This assumes the query always comes last.

```
function searchParse($str) {

    $output = array();

    // split by space
    $bits = explode(' ', $str);

    // process pairs
    foreach($bits as $id=>$pair) {

        // split the pair
        $pairBits = explode(':', $pair);

        // this was actually a pair
        if(count($pairBits) == 2) {

            // use left part of pair as index and push right part to array
            $output[$pairBits[0]][] = $pairBits[1];

            // remove this pair from $bits
            unset($bits[$id]);
        }

        // not a pair, presumably reached the query
        else {

            // exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // rebuild query with remains of $bits
    $output['q'] = implode(' ', $bits);

    return $output;
}
```

Test:

```
$string = 'is:issue is:open user:john Hello world';
$r = searchParse($string);
print_r($r);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [is] => Array
        (
            [0] => issue
            [1] => open
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
        )

    [q] => Hello world
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.